# How can list elements be used as factor names in R?

Tags: r

I have a list, e.g. mylist=c("A","B","C"), and I wish to use list elements to extract factors of a data frame in R.

If MyDataFrame has a column name "A", I can extract the column/factor as MyDataFrame$A. However,

```
MyDataFrame$mylist[1]
```

fails. At first I thought that this was because mycolumn[3] is "A" whereas I need $A without the quotes. However, using

```
MyDataFrame$as.name(mylist[1])
```

fails as well, presumably because R looks for the string as.name(mylist[1]) as a factor name rather than processing the function (the rror it gives is "attempt to apply non-function". Setting x=as.name(mylist[1]) and then using MyDataFrame$x runs into the same problem of x not being treated as a variable.

Is there a straightforward way to do this, as I need to loop over a long list of column names in order to call the factors of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this : rather than `$`

```
MyDataFrame[,mylist[1]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize that one could use factor names inside brackets rather than just numeric indices.

Comment: This link explain it ~ hope it can help http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html